# regex to find anything except "this String"

Tags: regex

I need a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to find anything except `this String`
example data is:

```
this is one line with this string only this should not match
this is another line but has no string in 
this String is another
and then this line should match also
```

I want to find and highlight the entire line, so the line
`this is one line with this string` is the only one that will be selected.

I tried `^(?!(this String)$)` but this find zero length match, so not much help, I tried adding `.*` in various places but don't understand how to do this.

Comment: What is the tool you are using?

Comment: Did you try `^(?:(?!\b(?:red|blue|green)\b).)*$`? BTW, why `and then this line should not match` shouldn't match? It has no `this string` in it.

Comment: How does `red,blue` etc come into picture?

Comment: So you want to find everything besides lines containing `this String`? Yet you drop two lines that don't contain it? - You should clarify your question doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: why and then this line should not match shouldn't match? It has no this string in it.
CORRECT sorry it should match, no i will try it thanks

Comment: i have updated to show better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that you don't need regex for this task at all. Look at these two pieces of code:

```
std::regex pattern("^((?!this string).)*$");
while (std::getline(infile, chkme)) {
    if (std::regex_match(chkme,pattern)) {
        std::cout << "Not found! " << chkme;
}}
```

and

```
std::string pattern = "this string";
while (std::getline(infile, chkme)) {
    if (chkme.find(pattern) == string::npos) {
        std::cout << "Not found! " << chkme;
}}
```

Comment: sorry dont understand what they should do.

Comment: second is much simpler to read. use of regular expressions is excessive for this simple case.